# Which is the badge awarded to the least amount of people?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges, statistics

Which is the rarest badge awarded/the least popular one/the one hardest to get?

Comment: Are you including tag badges? [Plenty of gold tag badges only awarded once](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold)

Comment: @AakashM and even more tag badges never awarded at all ;)

Comment: @Mołot and such tag badges do not exist until someone earn them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go. I have created [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/159921/list-of-rare-badges-exclude-tag-badges) in Data.SE to find this:

```sql
SELECT Name
  ,CASE Class WHEN 1 THEN 'Gold' WHEN 2 THEN 'Silver' ELSE 'Bronze' END AS Class
  ,COUNT(ID) AS Total_Awarded
 FROM Badges
 WHERE TagBased = 0
 GROUP BY Name,Class
 ORDER BY COUNT(ID);
```

I have excluded tag badges. And according to it [image: Sheriff] is the rarest badge which is awarded to users who have served as an elected moderator for at least 1 year.