# Which badge is the rarest?

Tags: support, badges

Which badges on this site are so rare very few people have earned them? Please tell me a badge that has less than ten people who have earned it. Also please don’t tell me badges that no one ever earned and never will. Please do tell me badges that no one has earned but can earn. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the badge awarded to the least amount of people?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216210/which-is-the-badge-awarded-to-the-least-amount-of-people). The SEDE query in the answer will get you the answer you're looking for, and you can run it for any SE site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each site has a [list of badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) with the number of times they've been awarded.

Not trying to brag, but on *this* site, i.e. Meta Stack Exchange, the only badge which is awarded only 1 time is [Illuminator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/248/illuminator). [Tenacious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/69/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/70/unsung-hero) could theoretically be awarded here but there's too much voting for the amount of questions here for those badges to be practically feasible.

Illuminator is also the [rarest badge in the entire network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300607/295232), at least among the ones which can be obtained on every site.

Comment: Are there any badges nobody has? Do new badges come out often?

Comment: No, not that often: Lifejacket and Lifeboat were the last to be added: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/ Another 'recent' addition is Census: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341214/4751173 but that was in 2017 already.

Comment: What about Shog9s ‘review’ badge?

Comment: @EkadhSingh or [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/321/site-recommendation) </brag>. Those are tag badges and generally left out when talking about badge rarity.

Comment: Okay, didn’t realize that tag badges are normally left out when talking about badge rarity, thank you,